# How work Mage :: helper in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I tried to understand this line of code.

```
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
```

1.for started was declared a variable `($_attributes)`

2.`Mage::helper('core')`helper is a method that loads an object? What is `core`? a file? where to find this file?

3.`decorateArray` is a method from `core class`?

Can you tell me please how this code works and give me a simple example?

I tried to make this short example in my page

```
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
<?php if($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)){
   echo "de vanzare";
}
?>
```

Perhaps the condition is evaluated false message and not displayed. I get no error, but not working.

I wanted to see if I understand how it works `Mage::helper` (that's why I made this example)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mage::helper('core') is an object of helper class Mage_Core_Helper_Data that is located in [/Core/Helper/Data.php](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Helper_Data.html). Please read the docs prior to starting on Magento.

Comment: @Cristi  core is module name and  decorateArray is a method in following class refer app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage::helper('core')` belongs to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper. You can find decorateArray() into data.php inside this path.

Mage folder contains core classes for magento.

Answer (score 0):

Mage::helper('myHelper') will load the called helper, here you load the Mage_Core_Helper_Data helper.

$_attributes will contain the result of the function you called, here the function decorateArray which is in Mage_Core_Helper_Data.